# How to to send notification in FB

Tags: facebook, notifications, fbml

How can I send Fb notification I have FBML app and I can not get it worked...
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notifications have been deprecated for a year now I believe.  Also, FBML apps are going to be deprecated going forward, so you should think about moving to IFrame.

There is a new "Request 2.0" that will allow you to send app-to-user requests, but it doesn't appear in the red notification counter towards the top of the page - it merely increases the bookmark counter.  All user-to-user requests will register in the red notification counter towards the top of the page though.

Comment: Thank you, "FBML apps are going to be deprecated"  that means that you will NOT WORK? When is this going to happen? Whay they do this, Whay di they made this so it can be removed after few years? Tnx!Adrian

Comment: See [link](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) for the FB developer roadmap.  New FBML apps will be disallowed starting March 11.  Going iframe will mean wider distribution of facebook social graph - leveraging FB connect.